# How to add rows to second table from the first table using Common table expression in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

For example, I have the first table and I want to fill the second table using the first table.

```
           Table A              
 Name   A    B   C   D
-----------------------
 name1  a1  b1  c1  d1
 name2  a2  b2  c2  d2



      Table B (Desired Format)      
  ID    Name    Code
 ----------------------
  1     name1   a1
  2     name1   b1
  3     name1   c1
  4     name1   d1
  5     name2   a2
  6     name2   b2
  7     name2   c2
  8     name2   d2
```

As per the suggestions of @Surendra Nath GM, I tried this

```
   DECLARE @counter as int
   SET @counter = 1;
  ;WITH Actual AS 
  (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY IDKEY) as ID  FROM Northwind.dbo.Table1
  WHERE 
   ),FIRST AS
  (
  SELECT ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY IDKEY))*4-3) AS ID,Name, A 
  FROM Northwind.dbo.Table1

   ),SECOND AS
  (
   SELECT ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY IDKEY))*4-2) AS ID, Name ,B
  from Northwind.dbo.Table1
   ), NEXT AS
  (
 SELECT ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY IDKEY))*4-1) AS ID, Name, C
  from Northwind.dbo.Table1next
 ), ________ as
 (
  SELECT ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY IDKEY))*4) AS ID, Name, D
from Northwind.dbo.Table1
 )

 @counter = @counter+1;
  )
  SELECT * FROM FIRST
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM SECOND
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM NEXT
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM _________
  ORDER BY ID
```

Here, what do I use after the "SECOND AS". I tried writing "THIRD AS" but apparently no such command exists so after some searching, I could write the third row using "NEXT AS" but I am completely clueless as to how do I insert the Fourth row.

I know I can simply write 4 insert commands for each of A,B,C and D but then I will get the not codes in the following order which is NOT desired:

```
Table B(NOT DESIRED IN THIS FORMAT)     
  ID    Name    Code
 ----------------------
  1     name1   a1
  2     name2   a2
  3     name1   b1
  4     name2   b2
  5     name1   c1
  6     name2   c2
  7     name1   d1
  8     name2   d2
```

Also, the desired format can be achieved using simple loops but in the project I am working on, there are around 200000 rows and the simple loops method takes a lot of time. So, I want to do it using CTE. Please help.

Comment: show your table structre of both table...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getting the ID will be the tricky part over here, in order to do that and use the set opertaions, you have to split the job into two and generate odd ID's for the select of A1,B1 and generate event ID's for the select of A2,B2

Shown as below

```
;WITH Actual AS 
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY Name) as RN, * FROM Table1
),FIRST AS
(
  SELECT ((RN*2)-1) AS ID,A1,B1 
  FROM TABLE1
  ORDER BY RN
),SECOND AS
(
  SELECT (RN*2) AS ID,A2,B2
  FROM TABLE1
  ORDER BY RN
)
SELECT * FROM FIRST
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM SECOND
```

if you have four columns then you can use the below query instead

```
;WITH Actual AS 
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY Name) as RN, * FROM Table1
),FIRST AS
(
  SELECT ((RN*2)-1) AS ID,A1,B1,C1,D1
  FROM TABLE1
  ORDER BY RN
),SECOND AS
(
  SELECT (RN*2) AS ID,A2,B2,C2,D2
  FROM TABLE1
  ORDER BY RN
)
SELECT * FROM FIRST
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM SECOND
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...this works for two columns. But the project I am working on has 4 columns. So, what do I use after "SECOND AS". I tried writing "THIRD AS" but apparently no such command exists so after some searching, I could write the third row using "NEXT AS" but I am completely clueless as to how do I insert the Fourth row.

Comment: @nie 4 columns, you mean you A1,B1,A2,B2,A3,B3? can you please give the same table schema as above, which will let us help you better

Comment: By 4 columns I mean, on Table 1 there will be 8 columns i.e. A1, A2,B1,B2,C1,C2,D1,D2  which would correspond to 4 columns ( A, B, C, D ) in Table 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two inserts:

```
insert into tableB(A, B)
    select A1, B1
    from tableA;

insert into tableB(A, B)
    select A2, B2
    from tableA;
```

Or union the table with one insert:

```
insert into tableB(A, B)
    select A1, B1
    from tableA union all
    select A2, B2
    from tableA;
```

This assumes that `id` is defined as `id int indentity(1, 1)` so it automatically increments.

If not, you could assign it as:

```
insert into tableB(id, A, B)
    select row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as id, A1, B1
    from (select A1, B1
          from tableA union all
          select A2, B2
          from tableA
         ) t
```

Comment: I wanted the answer such that A1 and A2 of each row should be together (as shown in Table 2) i.e. if I were to add a fourth column to Table 2 with the Header "Name", then the first two rows would have "ABD" in them. I am sorry, I should have clarified that in the question. Anyways, Thanks for the answer.